# Problem using a variable with space passed into ls in a shell script

Tags: bash, whitespace, ls

I'm trying to figure out how to handle a directory name with a space inside a shell script while passing it to ls. Below is a code sample - assuming that there is a directory called `Hello world` in the current directory, the first `ls` works, the second complains `ls: Hello\ World: No such file or directory`.

```
DST_DIR="Hello\ World"
ls Hello\ World
ls "${DST_DIR}"
```

Help. :(

Comment: The quotes already escape the space. `"Hello World"` is equivalent to `Hello\ World`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape sequences aren't processed after expanding variables, so you shouldn't put the backslash in the string. It's only needed when you're typing an unquoted string literally.

```
DST_DIR="Hello World"
ls "${DST_DIR}"
```